# Where and how to find compatible OBD bluetooth adapter

Tags: obd-ii, hyundai, sonata

I need a bluetooth OBD adapter compatible with `Hyundai Sonata 2002 2.0 Automatic UK`. I don't know much about cars and hence ending up asking for help. I would appreciate if someone can inform me where to get this adapter and how to know which type of adapters will fit in my car. I am also not sure if my car is OBD compatible and if there are some other types of standards that I need to look for. I also don't know if my car has ELM327 interface.

I am googling around and I will carry on doing so but as of now I can't find anything useful or maybe I am not looking for the right thing so any help will be much appreciated. Will [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Small-Elm327-Obd-ii-Bluetooth-Adapter/dp/B0076EBRYG/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t) work?

Comment: Did you found your OBD plug? Should be somewhere under the steering wheel (fuse box maybe) or at the middle console.

Comment: I'm sure the ELM327 is the model of the OBD-II reader you were showing us in the link and not an interface. Your car will have an OBD-II interface in it and the ELM327 should support your needs, as Allan pointed out below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three parts to do what you want to do. You need a plug in reader. The one on your link will do. This part reads the coding from your system and 'broadcasts' it. Then you need an Android smart phone to pick up the 'broadcast' and act as a display unit for the codings. The smart phone will need an app to do this. If you are still googling, look up OTC 3005; iOBD2; Torgue Pro, and make your choice. The DLC for the Sonata is found on the lower steering columm cowling.